# Setting maximum number of running processes

Tags: mac, macos

I've got program that create N processes, where N is input argument given in command line. I tried to increase this value and got 
`fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

Even when setting the relevant params I got the same results on the same value of N.

```
kern.maxproc
kern.maxprocperuid
```

Perhaps there's other places I need to refer to make more processes in my station Or maybe I need to apply the configuration change (I thought it's done automatically) ?

Seem like `fork` returns `errno = 23` which means :

```
#define ENFILE      23      /* Too many open files in system */
```

I also tried to increase the following values but it didn't help (although I doubt if it's relevant, since my processes are simple and doesn't access any file)

```
maxflies
maxfilesperproc
```

Also, rebooting the machine to make the new configuration effective, won't help in this case, as the params I've modified return to default value.

My program source code :

```
void DoWorkInChild() {
    sleep(10);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pids[100000];
    int i;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm grandParent %d n = %d \n", getpid(), n);
    /* Start children. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
                    printf("errno = %x \n", errno);
                    perror("fork");
                    abort();
            } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
                    DoWorkInChild();
                    exit(0);
            } else {
                    printf("I'm process %d \n", pids[i]);
            }
    }

    /* Wait for children to exit. */
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    while (n > 0) {
            pid = wait(&status);
            printf("Child with PID %ld exited with status 0x%x.\n", (long)pid, status);
            --n;          
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is the value of `N`? Have you seen the [Mac OS X Hint: 
A solution for Mac OS X process limits](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=200311151254441)? Are you the developer of the program creating the processes?

Comment: @GrahamMiln, I've tried to Use N=500, while i got ~320 processes already running. when setting maxprocperuid=1024 and maxproc=2048, it should work as i'm the only active user. I also set the file /etc/sysctl.conf but it didn't help (although after reboot the configuration remains).

Comment: Good to see you found a solution. If you find your processes are causing thrashing, consider using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2) to queue up your tasks. GCD will then run as many as you have available cores – and may even be faster than launching them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, I've found the following script that should be run prior to xnu benchmark tests.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Raising process limits
echo limit maxproc 1000 2000 >> /etc/launchd.conf

echo Done.
```

Now, it's working but still cannot see any changes in /etc/sysctl...
I wonder what configuration did it change eventually ...

Comment: `/etc/launchd.conf` has been ignored since 10.10 when launchd was redesigned, so that should not work unless you are on 10.9 or earlier.